# Define multiple click regions on one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to figure out the best way to go about doing this.

Basically I have one image that is the map of the United States and I want to be able to define a click region for each state. (so they have to be odd shaped)

I've done some research about defining hit regions in html5 canvas and with javascript. Although I haven't found much on creating odd shaped regions..

Is this the best way to go about it? Do y'all have any other suggestions?

I'm also wanting to be able to highlight the individual region once the mouse is over it and have it change colors based on the click order so the region defined has to be fairly accurate.

Would it be best to split each state up into different images and then use absolute positioning inside a main container?

Comment: Try looking into d3 and geojson drawing. You can assign click listeners for each svg object that d3 generates.

Comment: Is this specifically for the US map, or are there going to be other images you want to do this with? I'm pretty sure there's a jQuery map plugin that does exactly this.\

Comment: Yup, here it is: http://jvectormap.com/

Comment: @tymeJV Yeah, it's only for a US map. But, I figured if I learned how to do this manually I would gain the knowledge to do it later for other scenarios. Thanks! Can't believe I didn't stumble across that.. My Goggle-Foo must be off today.

Comment: @n388mm -- Understandable, might be worth-while taking a peak at the source of the plugins. Here's codegeekz 16 best map plugins list: http://codegeekz.com/best-jquery-map-plugins/

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `<map>` like this:

```
<img src="yourImage.gif" width="99" height="99" alt="YourImage" usemap="#YourMap">
//The usemap attribute must match the name attribute of your map.
<map name="YourMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="path1.htm" alt="Path1">
    //Coords are x, y of the top left corner and the bottom right corner of the rectangle
    <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="path2.htm" alt="Path2">
    //Coords are the x, y of the center of the circle and the lenght of half the diameter of the circle
    <area shape="poly" coords="124,58,8, 1" href="path3.htm" alt="Path3">
    //Coords are the x, y of each points in the shape drew for an pentagone (5 corners)
    //The coords attribute could look like this coords="0, 0, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 12, 13"
    //I know this dont make a pentagone but it does ilustrate that you need 5 pairs of     
    //numbre in the coords and that if you need more of them you can add however you need .
</map>
```

Then in the href attribute of the area tag you can put your own path to where the user goes when he click the area.

Comment: Nice dude! This looks like a perfect solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very easy to create selectable portions of an image that snap exactly to a map so insted lets use d3, SVG and geojson to draw the United States as an svg.

```
var width = 1000,  // create constants for svg width and height
    height = 500,
    projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();  //get projection
// albersusa is a special projection for the united states
var svg = d3.select("body")  //select the body and create the svg with the width and height constants.
  .append("svg")
  .attr({
    width:width,
    height:height
  });

var g = svg.append("g"); // append a svg group for the map

d3.json("geo.json", function(data){  //fetch the json data
  console.log(data.features);  
    g.selectAll("path")  //draw the map
    .data(data.features)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(projection))
      .on("click", function(d){  // add onclick listener that logs the state clicked on.
        console.log("You clicked on " + d.properties.NAME, d);
      });
});
```

The advantage of using SVG over images is that svg elements can be animated using CSS3 transions and they can also be manipulated using javascript.
I've hosted an example of this on my [google drive](https://googledrive.com/host/0B_0L-A0ICAeeX3hVektlaWZzbXc/index.html). Open the console and start clicking on the states.

Comment: This is awesome! I had no idea you could use svg and geojson like that. (Shows how much more there is to learn) lol

Thanks Dude!

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few of the javascript canvas libraries can help you out with this sort of thing, for instance Raphael ( http://raphaeljs.com/world/ ) or KineticJS ( http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/ )